# Android Phone as Remote Control for Android Tv Device, using WIFI

Tags: java, android, kotlin, live-connect-sdk

Android Tv remote, pairing connection and utilization of Connect SDK to operate keys.

I'm working to develop android App that is use as a **TV-REMOTE-CONTROL** over same Wifi,

For this I'm using and following guidelines by **Connect-SDK-For-Android** documented here (https://connectsdk.com/en/latest/). I'm utilizing sample provided to test the SDK provided here **Connect SDK Android Sample.** I found this method is simple and fast to be achieve my requirement.

Issue why I'm here that Connect SDK is calling for TV Capabilities to perform remote functions, when I run this code it is showing me connected TV's list over same WIFI. But when I choose or select TV option it directly connect to TV without asking for pairing code that should be enabled on TV. Indirect connection it only allows me to change TV VOLUME through connected protocol.

Secondly, Connect SDK is using multiple service's like Chromecast, DIAL, DLNS etc.; for single device and when listing Connected TV, it list single TV multiple times depending on Services enabled.

I required to enable Number Keys and Key Control (up,down,right,left) Power Control Key, Connect-SDK utilizing CapabilityMethods and other interfaces to enable the all keys functionality.

I required guide how could I achieve my required functionality TV-Remote-Control, any other way to get my solution would be appreciated but I'm prioritizing Connect-SDK method.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a Samsung smart TV using connectsdk and facing the same problems. 

I'm able to list devices (same device is being listed multiple times), but after connect to a device: I'm not able to do any kind of pairing (even though I set pairing ON and to MIXED type). 

I'm also not able to get any kind of capabilities except for VolumeControl to test to true and when I try to execute a Volume command I get Internal Server Error. 

Unfortunately there is no much information about connectsdk, thinking on my next move, maybe I will try to connect to the tv using websockets.

Comment: @Gernan same issue I'm facing too, it looks a clean and save platform to attach device to TV but has many ambiguities, and complexities to be handled. Thanks for sharing,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not much support online for ConnectSDK. I'm making a TV remote app myself on Github. I'm having to figure much of it out for myself also. Is your code on github?

Regarding it showing the same device multiple times, the way I solved it was to create a "deviceKey". It's basically a string variable. I combined the device name + the IP address into the variable and unless each deviceKey is unique and different, it won't be added into my deviceList array. That's where all I stored all the Connectable devices found by discovery manager.